# ad hoc network maximal distance

Tags: networking, network-programming

I wasn't successful finding the maximal distance between two devices connected in adhoc network. Could you give any advice about this topic?

What I am trying to do is let's have 2 cars, in first one there is pc, in second one there is pc and I want to send some information over the network.

Do you think adhoc nettwork is good or is it better to have router for this?